# C# to Oxygene code converter

Tags: c#, delphi, codedom, oxygene

I know CodeGear made [BabelCode](http://lingua.codegear.com/babelcode/) that uses the Code DOM to convert C# to Delphi for .NET.  I am curious if there are any other similar tools to convert C# to Delphi Prism?  If not, what is involved in using the Code DOM to create one (yeah, that is open ended!)

**Update**: This is now built into Delphi Prism.  Just paste or import your C# and you have Oxygene aka Delphi Prism Code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in its early stages but Carlo just published a first revision of his open source "C# to Oxygene" tool:

http://code.remobjects.com/p/csharptoxy/

Comment: FYI: This is now built into Delphi Prism.  Just paste or import your C# and you have Oxygene aka Delphi Prism Code.

Comment: Link is dead. So is ShineOn. Whats up with that?

Answer (score 3):

One option I saw was to use .NET Reflector on the C# compiled assembly.  It has an Oxygene syntax.  That is kind of the long way around and not exactly optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Use BabelCode to convert your C# to Delphi, and then use [Oxidizer](http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Oxidizer) to convert Delphi to Prism. Not a stellar idea, I realize, but it might at least be a little more automatable than going through Reflector. Good luck.

Comment: Nope! I tried BabelCode once or twice back when it was first introduced, and I've never used Oxidizer. Haven't even gotten around to trying Prism yet. Like I said: Good luck. :)

Comment: I tried BabelCode with some newer C# code with LINQ syntax in it, and the output was blank. . . . .

Comment: I guess that doesn't surprise me. LINQ didn't exist yet when BabelCode was made.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't updated BabelCode in a long time -- since we stopped developing C#Builder in fact. That's where the guts for the service came from.